# How to add a Model object into my AJAX.ActionLink

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an Html.ActionLink that I need to post to the server:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Some Text", "controller", "service", Model, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @id = "someText" })
```

I tried Turning this into an AJAX post with:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Some Text", "controller", "service", Model, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @id = "someText" }, new AjaxOptions(){HttpMethod = "POST"})
```

There is no overload for string, string, string, object, object like the above Html.Actionlink.

I am not very familiar with AJAX but is there a way to tell AJAX to pass the same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the ordering of the parameters incorrect.  The `AjaxOptions` come before the attributes.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Some Text", "controller", "service", Model, new AjaxOptions(){HttpMethod = "POST"}, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @id = "someText" })
```

Comment: I figured I missed something small Thanks!